# For loops and if statements in Hooks?

Tags: javascript, react-native, for-loop, if-statement

Is there a way where I can use `for loops` and `if statements` without breaking the hook rule? To elaborate, I am currently trying to compare two lists (`allData` and `currentSelection`) and if there are similarities, I will add them to another list (`favData`). However, I am constantly either having visibility issues or errors. If I can get some help, I would much appreciate it!

```
const [favData, setFavData] = useState([]);    
useEffect(() => {     
    getFilterFavMeal();   
}, []);    
function getFilterFavMeal() {        
    allData.forEach((mealList) => {            
        currentSelection.forEach((mealList2) => {                
            if (mealList["menu_item"]["menu_item_id"] === mealList2.value) {                             
            // with push, I have visibility issues 
//                       favData.push(mealList);                       
                setFavData(mealList);                
            }            
        });        
    });        
    setFavData(favData);    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set function that useState returns updates the state and schedules a re-render of the component so that the UI can update. It doesn't make sense to call the set function many times in one render.

You also don't want to mutate React state by using functions like `push`.

Since it looks like favData is deterministic, you can simply remove it from the component state and calculate it in the render loop.

`const favData = allData.filter(a => currentSelection.some(c => c.value === a.menu_item.menu_item_id));`

Answering your original question, of course you can use loops. As long as you don't mutate the existing state object. And don't set the state more than once per render.

```
const FF = () => { 
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  const addStuffToList = () => {
    const tail = Array.from(new Array(3)).map((_e, i) => i);
    // Build a new array object and use that when setting state
    setList([...list, ...tail]);
  }

  const forLoop = () => {
    const tail = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      tail.push(i);
    }
    // Same thing
    setList([...list, ...tail]);
  }

  return ...
};
```

Comment: very insightful! Thank you so much!